# How to mock restTemplate exchange method while writing spring cloud azure function

Tags: java, junit, mocking, azure-functions, mockito

I have a spring cloud azure function which is written in java.

```java
ResponseEntity<Object> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<Object>() {});
```

From this above code I am trying to execute the url using restTemplate and getting the response back in json.

Now while writing the junit test cases for this code I don't want to execute he actual url
Instead I wanted to mock the exchange method and retuned a json mock response.

But always it is calling my actual URL which I don't want and  exchange method is not getting mocked.

Here is full class code:

```java
@Component
public class TktService implements Function<FunctionInput, AirTravelDocument> {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    @Value("${tkt.url}")
    private String tkturl;

    public AirTravelDocument apply(FunctionInput input) {
        String param = input.getParam();
        ExecutionContext context = input.getContext();
        ITelemetryOperator telemetryOperator =        TelemetryOperator.Builder.newBuilder(context.getTraceContext().getTraceparent()).build();
        telemetryOperator.logInfo(context, "Entered handler method");
        String url = tkturl + param;
        telemetryOperator.logInfo(context, "Param : " + param);
        telemetryOperator.logInfo(context, "Establishing connection with ODS API: " + url);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(null, headers);
        ResponseEntity<AirTravelDocument> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity,
                new ParameterizedTypeReference<AirTravelDocument>() {
                });
        AirTravelDocument airTravelDocument = response.getBody();
        telemetryOperator.logInfo(context, "Response fetched from ODS API");
        return airTravelDocument;
    }
}
```

Tried below junit test case code:

```java
final RestTemplate restTemplate = mock(RestTemplate.class);
doReturn(response).when(restTemplate).exchange("url", HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<AirTravelDocument>(){});
```

Note - response which I already created which I wanted to return.